# Is there a description error in the tsconfig.json file?

Tags: typescript

in tsconfig.json

```json
 "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
```

and in typescript website

> All module imports with non-relative names are assumed to be relative to the baseUrl.

Comment: Do not understand the question, add more details?

Comment: in website it's 'non-relative', but in tsconfig.json it's 'non-absolute', which one is right?